# Interaction between Unlocked iPhone and iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

I just unlocked my iPhone 3G 4.1

My question is:
1) Can I sync the apps that I purchased previously before unlocking through iTunes?
2) Can this unlocked phone be used for iPhone development?
3) Will I be able to sync music through iTunes on this unlocked phone?

These questions may be silly. But I am a newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes to all three questions.

I've done all three before I switched to android so I wouldn't *have to*!

However I don't think this is a stackoverflow question :)